# Не передаеться data в state. aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

мне надо получить sale_id, buyer_id в handle_contact_accept. Мучаюсь 2 часа ничего не могу сделать) Current state: None

```html
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data.startswith('contact'), state=SearchForm)
async def sale_info(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    try:
        #await state.finish()
        user_id = callback_query.from_user.id
        # Извлекаем id продажи из callback_data
        sale_id = int(callback_query.data.split('_')[-1])
        seller_id = db.get_user_id_sale(sale_id)
        language = db.user_language(seller_id)
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data["sale_id"] = sale_id
            data["buyer_id"] = user_id
        await state.update_data(sale_id=sale_id, buyer_id=user_id)
        print(data["sale_id"], data["buyer_id"])
        keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
        if language == "RU":
            buttonYes = types.KeyboardButton(text="Согласиться", request_contact=True)
            buttonNo = types.KeyboardButton(text="Отказаться", callback_data=f"decline_{user_id}")
        else:
            buttonYes = types.KeyboardButton(text="Погодитися", request_contact=True)
            buttonNo = types.KeyboardButton(text="Відмовитися", callback_data=f"decline_{user_id}{sale_id}")
        keyboard.add(buttonYes, buttonNo)

        if language == 'RU':
            await bot.send_message(seller_id, text='С вами хотят связаться насчёт продажи/обмена!', reply_markup=keyboard)
        else:
            await bot.send_message(seller_id, text="З вами хочуть зв'язатися щодо продажу/обміну!", reply_markup=keyboard)

        language = db.user_language(user_id)

        if language == "RU":
            await bot.send_message(user_id,
                                   text="Заявка на общение успешно отправлена! Вам прийдет контакт пользователя после того как он подтверит общение с вами.")
        else:
            await bot.send_message(user_id,
                                   text="Заявку на спілкування успішно надіслано! Вам прийде контакт користувача після того, як він підтвердить спілкування з вами.")
    except ValueError as E:
        print(f"{E}")


@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.CONTACT)#,state=SearchForm.Contact)
async def handle_contact_accept(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    print("Current state:", current_state)
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        language = db.user_language(user_id)
        # Извлекаем id продажи из callback_data
        data = await state.get_data()
        print(f"data: {data}")
        sale_id = data['sale_id']
        buyer_id = data['buyer_id']
        title = db.get_sale_info(sale_id)
        print("Sale ID:", sale_id)
        print("Buyer ID:", buyer_id)
        print(title)
        if message.contact:
            contact = message.contact
            phone_number = contact.phone_number
            first_name = contact.first_name
            last_name = contact.last_name if contact.last_name else None
            if language == "RU":
                await bot.send_message(buyer_id, text=f"Контакт пользователя с объявления {title[2]}")
                await bot.send_contact(buyer_id, phone_number, first_name, last_name)
            else:
                await bot.send_message(buyer_id, text=f"Контакт користувача з оголошення {title[2]}")
                await bot.send_contact(buyer_id, phone_number, first_name, last_name)
        else:
            print("error")
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f"{e}")
```